# UITableViewController orientation within a UIPopover

Tags: ios, orientation, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I would like to display a `UITableViewController` within a `UIPopoverController`, but the catch here is that I would like to have the `UITableViewController` displayed in a landscape orientation even though the `viewController` which is displaying the `UIPopoverController` is in portrait orientation.

If there is a way to set the orientation of a `UITableViewController`, that would be best, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Any thoughts on how to do this would be appreciated?

Comment: Have you tried returning NO in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for the orientation you do not want?